# How to remove a part of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code :

```
var data = [];
$("#btn").click(function(){
    total++;
    data.push({        
        id : total,
        "cell": [
            "val1",
            "val2",
            "val3",
        ]
    });
});
```

Every time that user clicks on `btn` button, I add some values to the data object. Now my question is here that how I can remove the part that has `id = X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .splice() at position X

```
var data = [{id : total, "cell" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"]}[, ...repeat];

var X = 0; // position to remove
data.splice(X,1);
```

extension:

```
for (var i=data.length-1; 0 < i; i--) {
    if (data[i].id == X) {
        data.splice(X,1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use
        `x = {id1: "some value"}`
        `delete x.id1`

That's about it

Answer (score 1):

```
const {  whatIDontWant, ...theRest } = everything;
return {theRest};
```

Let the LHS equal the RHS, whatIDontWant is excluded from theRest because of uniqueness of properties within an object evaluated when spreading. Therefore theRest is an object without the unwanted property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative idea. Using the id as a key in an object instead:

```
var data = {};

$("#btn").click(function(){
    total++;
    data[total] = {
        cell: [
            "val1",
            "val2",
            "val3"
        ]
    };
});
```

Then to delete the object that has that specific id you can do:

`delete data[id];`

or

`data[id] = null;`

to just null it.

This way you remove the complexity from having an array there too.