# javascript array.splice() does not remove element in the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a remove[] array which has all the index positions of all the element with 0 in the data array (as below).

data array:

```
Retail,1,Utilities,1,Food & Restaurant,3,No Data,4,Construction,0,Non-profit,1,Financial Services,12,Technology,2,Law,3,Religion,3,Retired,2,Insurance,0,Real Estate,2,Audit,3,Business Organizations,3,Media & Marketing,0,Education,3,Transportation,0,Manufacturing,0,Entertainment & Sports,0,Architecture & Engineering,0,Cultural Institutions,0,Government,0,Banking,0,Health Care,0,Business Services,0
```

my javascript

```
   var remove =  [];          
    $.each(options.series[0].data, function(index, item) {
    if (options.series[0].data[index][1] == 0)
    {                    
        //options.series[0].data.splice(index,1);  
        remove[index] = index;                                      

    }

    for (i=0; i<=remove.length; i++)
    {
    //alert(remove);                
    if (remove[i] != undefined)
        options.series[0].data.splice(remove[i],1);

    }
```

data array after splice(). A lot of elements with 0 are still there.

```
Retail,1,Utilities,1,Food & Restaurant,3,No Data,4,Non-profit,1,Financial Services,12,Technology,2,Law,3,Religion,3,Retired,2,Insurance,0,Audit,3,Business Organizations,3,Media & Marketing,0,Education,3,Manufacturing,0,Entertainment & Sports,0,Cultural Institutions,0,Banking,0,Business Services,0
```

if i changed the splice to include replacement element

```
options.series[0].data.splice(remove[i],1,'removed');
```

All 0 elements are removed from the data array. huh?

```
Retail,1,Utilities,1,Food & Restaurant,3,No Data,4,removed,Non-profit,1,Financial Services,12,Technology,2,Law,3,Religion,3,Retired,2,removed,Real Estate,2,Audit,3,Business Organizations,3,removed,Education,3,removed,removed,removed,removed,removed,removed,removed,removed,removed
```

How do I remove all the 0 elements in my data array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete from array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362412/delete-from-array-in-javascript)

Comment: It looks like the members of the array should be strings. You haven't quoted them so they are interpreted as identifiers, you should be getting errors - unless you aren't posting the real code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every time you remove one, you're making any further cached indices obsolete because the array  from that point forward is reindexed.

As a result, you're removing the wrong items after the first.

You should iterate the `remove` array in reverse instead.

```
var i = remove.length;
while (i--) {
    if (remove[i] != undefined)
        options.series[0].data.splice(remove[i],1);
}
```

---

Additionally, you can improve the performance and get rid of the `undefined` test if you simply `.push()` each index into the `remove` array...

```
remove.push(index);
```

Comment: It should work forwards too **provided** there is a one–for–one swap, since the inserted element replaces the removed one the indexes are not affected. Otherwise, yes, it should be done backwards.

Comment: @RobG: The inserted element is part of the working code. OP stated that doing an insertion solves the issue, but an insertion isn't wanted. EDIT: Saw your update... yes, provided there's an insertion, it will work.

Comment: Excellent. That works. I was also wondering how to get rid of the undefined values in remove[]. You read my mind and answered :).

Comment: @EverydayImSeeSharping: Glad it worked. :) FYI, unless you have another use for the `remove` Array, you could always just reverse iterate the `options.series[0].data` Array directly, and do the `splice()` right there.

Comment: @amNot—a few distractions when typing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that splice was removing the wrong element from the array. I saw the answer with the while loop but the solution that I made is :

```
var index = jQuery.inArray(element, arr);
arr.splice(index,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your original array and the first result array, you'll notice that non-0 elements ARE being removed. The problem from what I can tell is that your array `remove` is looking for indices that have since been shifted over one to the left upon the removal of previous ones. You will need to add a correcting adjustment for this in your final `for` loop, or approach this another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the elements from an array, it's better don't use `splice` but `length`:

```
options.series[0].data.length = 0;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Update:

I misunderstood the question. In your case I will probably filter out the elements that are zero, instead of makes two loop (one for collect them, and one for remove them). So, something like:

```
function isNotZero(item) {return item[1] !== 0}

var filtered = options.series[0].data.filter(isNotZero);

options.series[0].data = filtered;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

If the browser you want to support doesn't implement ES5, I will suggest to you to use a shim for all the es5 methods (in that page there is one for filter), or library like [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

Comment: Not all elements are being removed. OP is building a list of the indices of elements that have the value `0`, and only removing those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it pretty fast this way:

```
var dataArr = ["Retail",1,"Utilities",1,"Food & Restaurant",3,"No Data",4,"Construction",0,"Non-profit",1,"Financial Services",12,"Technology",2,"Law",3,"Religion",3,"Retired",2,"Insurance",0,"Real Estate",2,"Audit",3,"Business Organizations",3,"Media & Marketing",0,"Education",3,"Transportation",0,"Manufacturing",0,"Entertainment & Sports",0,"Architecture & Engineering",0,"Cultural Institutions",0,"Government",0,"Banking",0,"Health Care",0,"Business Services",0];

var item = 0; // value of the item to remove

while (dataArr.indexOf(item) > -1) {
 dataArr.splice(dataArr.indexOf(item), 1);
}

console.log(dataArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a library called DevBox.Linq.JS

It basically adds Linq type functionality to Javascript Arrays. For example, it adds "Remove":

```
   Array.prototype.Remove = function (condition) {
    if (condition == undefined) {
        console.error('Informe a expressão para executar a tarefa.')
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0 ; i < this.length ; i++) {
        if (condition(this[i]))
            this.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

This way you can use it with a lambda like this:

```
myArray.remove(i=>i=="valueToDelete");
```

Hope it helps, It already has all the functionality so you don't have to deal with that pesky splice.